# Use logback in grails 3

Tags: logging, grails, logback

Grails 3 uses `logback` as the default system of logging.

I need a example of how use `logback` in grails 3 in this form

```
log.info("some Info")
```

Comment: have you seen this? http://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/03/24/grails_logback.html

Answer (score 14):

You have to set the fourth argument of the logger config to `false`:

```
logger('grails.app.controllers', INFO, ['STDOUT'], false)
```

then the logging is not displayed twice.

I think that's because the `root` logger catches `INFO` too.

Comment: You don't have to add the 'false' (i.e. additivity flag) if you also remove the `['STDOUT']` part. You get duplicate logging because (without the false), you're telling logback to append via the root logger (to STDOUT) AND via this specific logger. Removing STDOUT means it will only append via the root logger. See [the documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html) for an explanation of the additivity flag.

Comment: @GreenGiant 's comment was the solution for me in Grails 3.2.1.  Logging worked well for "run-app" but not for "test-app".  Then I noticed that the root logger configuration treated "dev" specially.  I just expanded the logic to include the 'test' env, then logging appeared with no duplicates:

`if ((Environment.isDevelopmentMode() || Environment.currentEnvironment == Environment.TEST) ...) {
...`

Comment: Logback Additivity Example → https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-additivity-example/

Answer (score 4):

I was just looking into this, because I had similar a similar question. Grails 3 does use Logback for logging configuration, but the AST transform still uses Apache Commons Logging.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-logging/src/main/groovy/org/grails/compiler/logging/LoggingTransformer.java

It then uses the jcl-over-slf4j bridge to map it all back into all back into Logback.

According to the mailing list, http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-1-1-Is-it-possible-to-replace-the-injected-log-object-td4638834.html, to replace the injected `log` globally, you have to exclude the logging dependencies and replace the AST Transformer with your own.

The Logback plugin that the blog post in the comment above mentions provides this: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-logback/blob/master/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/logging/Slf4jTransformer.java. However, it seems like a lot of redundancy, as Grails 3 already has Logback support.

If you don't want to go through that work to change the log injection, you can override the logger by annotating the class with `@Slf4j` and that will override the logger for that class.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class)
```

This works but I'm also wondering if grails 3 can auto inject `log`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this and it works fine. This is from [petclinic](https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-petclinic/blob/master/grails-app/conf/logback.groovy) example.

Additional details avalable at [logback docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html)

```
import grails.util.BuildSettings
import grails.util.Environment


appender('STDOUT', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%level %logger - %msg%n"
    }
}

root(ERROR, ['STDOUT'])

if(Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
    def targetDir = BuildSettings.TARGET_DIR
    if(targetDir) {

        appender("FULL_STACKTRACE", FileAppender) {

            file = "${targetDir}/stacktrace.log"
            append = true
            encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
                pattern = "%level %logger - %msg%n"
            }
        }
        logger("StackTrace", ERROR, ['FULL_STACKTRACE'], false )
    }
}
```

Comment: I've run into an issue that has made me question this code: did you confirm that data is actually going into the stacktrace.log file? It may look like it is working because stacktraces hit stdout, but my experience has been that it doesn't actually hit the stacktrace.log file. So I'm trying to figure out if it is just me or if this is an issue with almost all the examples on the internet.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723285/why-does-stacktrace-log-not-fill-with-logback-in-grails-3) -- it appears that this will not log to the stacktrace.log file.

Answer (score 0):

Needed this as well in Grails 3. Found this post by mrhaki:

[grails 3 logging](http://mrhaki.blogspot.nl/2015/04/grails-goodness-set-log-level-for.html)

I tested this on a Quartz job. I added the following line in `logback.groovy`

```
logger("grails.app.jobs", INFO, ['STDOUT'])
```

Using test log in the quartz job:

```
log.info "test " + new Date()
```

shows log info in the console

```
INFO grails.app.jobs.myapp.TestJob - test Tue Oct 20 10:07:31 CEST 2015
```

Funny thing is happening. I see 2 duplicate lines for each `log.info`

```
log.info "test"
log.info "test2"
System.out.println("test"3)
```

Gives me:

```
INFO grails.app.jobs.myapp.TestJob - test
INFO grails.app.jobs.myapp.TestJob - test
INFO grails.app.jobs.myapp.TestJob - test2
INFO grails.app.jobs.myapp.TestJob - test2
test3
```

Comment: Adding `false` to `logger("grails.app.jobs", INFO, ['STDOUT'], false)` will remove duplicate log entries.